# Website with a tricky structure with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my tricky problem. I'm trying to do this:

> http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=767312test.gif

(More clear than an explication I think).

My structure :

```
<header></header>

<div class="section">
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="img"><img src="img1.png"/></div>
</div>

<div class="section">
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="img"><img src="img2.png"/></div>
</div>

<div class="section">
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="img"><img src="img3.png"/></div>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

**Important informations :**

- "Header" is fix
- "Content" fit to the screen less the height of header
- Every "section" are the same but with different content
- When the image comes to an end, the "content" div is unfixed.

I am using "section" for implementing a next and previous button in the header (with anchors).

My problem is the scrolling part. I am really lost when I try to fix the "content" div. I don't know how to fix everything except the scroll of the image in the active "img" div   when the active "content" div hits the header. (Everyone follows? Look here : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=767312test.gif

For the scrolling part in the "img" div, I was thinking use a sort of "overflow:scroll" but the scrollbar is really awful.

I don't know if it's enough clear. If there is any problem I can complete my problem. I am not very comfortable with complex structures in html with JS.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: using jquery it is possible

Comment: What happens if the viewport is higher?

Comment: An how is scrolling done? should it be one big scrollbar at the side?

Comment: this animation is making me feel a bit sick :(

Comment: No, I don't understand your graphics. It's nice, but lacks an explanation of what it abstracts. Are you looking for an animation? Which brings the same div text&content repeatedly? Are you asking how to make your elements scrollable? Are you looking for a parallax scroll?

Comment: The scrolling is the big at the side!

Comment: @Rahul: No. That will usually make it worse. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: Each section part is different, you can imagine a project in each one. In my example there is 3 "section" so 3 projects. The gif is looping, but you can imagine that it goes to the next "section" div. And it's stop when every "section" are passed. I don't know if it's parallax or not..

Comment: @Uooo, The viewport is hiding when is higher. Like a normal scroll!

Comment: Ok i think i understood what you are talking just take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/CwhpU/ i just made a simple one with no parallax, you need to use parallax on image to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty close to what you're asking for (using CSS only).

This relies on the fact that the backgrounds are solid colors. It uses various specifically-defined `height` properties as well that match some `padding` properties.

The `.top-bar` and `.bottom-bar` elements can probably be changed to pseudo elements if you don't want the extra HTML.

**HTML:**

```
<header>Header</header>

<div class="top-bar"></div>
<div class="bottom-bar"></div>

<div class="section">
    <div class="text">Section 1 Text</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="img"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/1000"/></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <div class="text">Section 2 Text</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="img"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/2000"/></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <div class="text">Section 3 Text</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="img"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/3000"/></div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
}

header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

footer {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
}

.section {
    min-height: 400px;
}

.text {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 50px;
}

.content {
    background-color: green;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.img {
    background-color: yellow;
    min-height: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
}

.img > img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.top-bar, .bottom-bar {
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.top-bar {
    top: 100px;
}

.bottom-bar {
    bottom: 0;
}

footer, .text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
}
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/GaDzL/1/)

---

For an *almost* completely correct solution, here is one with some jQuery involved.

**New CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
}

header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

footer {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
}

.section {
    min-height: 400px;
}

.text {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 50px;
}

.content {
    background-color: green;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.img {
    background-color: yellow;
    min-height: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
}

.img > img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.top-bar, .bottom-bar {
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.top-bar {
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.bottom-bar {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 7;
}

footer, .text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 8;
}

.img-fix {
    bottom: 40px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 6;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").each(function(){
        $(this).append($(this).html());
        $(this).find(".img + .img").wrap("<div class='img-fix'></div>");
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeImgFix();
    });

    resizeImgFix();
});

function resizeImgFix() {
    $(".img-fix").height($(window).height() - $("header").height() - $(".top-bar").height() - $(".bottom-bar").height());
    $(".img-fix").each(function(){
        $(this).scrollTop($(this).prop("scrollHeight"));
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/GaDzL/2/)

Note: It duplicates the `.img` element and its children. This could be memory intensive depending. However, it does make it work as intended without any visual lag or artifacts.

Comment: Ok. You just made it. With only css.(It's really impressing me.) Special mention for kitties!

Comment: Thanks guys. I've added some jQuery onto it to give it an exact match to your GIF if you're interested. I suppose it's progressively enhanced now that I think about it. So it will still look good if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: Hum I just see a thing. The bottombar and the topbar is visible every time. The problem is that I don't want to see the "bottom" of the green div until the "yellow" div is centered.

Comment: More precisely, I don't want that the yellow div seems to increase in height but that it appears from the bottom of the page.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean about the bottom bar. I'll think about that. In the meantime, there's no way to fix that in the pure CSS version; however, I'll look into a solution for it in the jQuery version.

Comment: EDIT : More precisely, I don't want that the yellow div seems to increase in height but that it appears from the bottom of the page. The problem is  that the yellow block needs to have a specific height like 500px for being centered in the green block for bigger or smaller screens. It means that margin around the yellow div must be extensible.

Comment: So this is as far as I can go at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/GaDzL/3/ The issue is that the `z-index` values needed to do what you want are impossible using my technique. So you'll have to switch `.top-bar`'s `z-index` to `9` when it is scrolling the top portion of a yellow box and to `5` when it is scrolling the bottom portion of a yellow box. Since math is difficult when I'm tired, I think I'll let you or someone else do that. I'm not sure of another solution at the moment (but again, I'm sleepy). I'll think more about it after sleep if no one's determined a solution.

Comment: @SombreErmine I just uploaded a "new version" of the gif. http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=767312test.gif. I think it's more clear than before. I would create a fake browser(the old yellow div) inside which a fake content (a simple picture) will scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the new graphic. That is much clearer now. I've got an idea on how to do that. It requires JavaScript, but it should be possible. I don't have time to explore the solution at the moment since I'm currently working, but the gist: (1) Lock scrolling past certain `div` elements if their internal `iframe` is not scrolled all the way in the direction you are scrolling; (2) Increase the height of the parent document to include the heights of the `iframe` documents (possibly minus their viewports); (3) Somehow match up the position of the parent scrollbar with the `iframe` scroll positions

Comment: @SombreErmine Hey! Did you find something useful? (even a small idea) I am always stuck at the same point and I become a bit crazy! I think I found something that could be interesting :  http://www.wired.co.uk/magazine/archive/2013/07/features/the-life-of-pi

Comment: I haven't had the chance to look at it yet, but just to make sure by looking at your GIF again... are you planning to have external webpages inside the `iframe`s? If you are, then it is practically impossible to get the external document's height due to cross-domain security walls (and thus probably not possible). If they're internal webpages or just `div`s, then it should still be possible. The page you linked is what I imagined. It uses JavaScript to change the images from absolute to fixed positions based on `document.scrollTop` values. (Absolute positions also depend on `scrollTop` values)

Comment: Oh no, you have just a picture in each Iframe, a simple screenshot of a full webpage, no dynamic content here!